# Dim or Brighten Display via Terminal in OS X

Tags: macos, command-line

Premise: All OS functionality is code
Conclusion: I must have a way to emulate said code.

I would like to figure out how to have the exact same brightening/dimming display mechanism currently mapped to `F1/F2` on my keyboard but via `Terminal`. I've googled and found a number of references to `pmset`, which is fascinating, but not the same goal.

Any thoughts on bash/c++ or other cli-based tools I can use to dim or brighten my display in OSx 10.6.7?

Comment: I have no idea about the topic, but a quick Google yields http://mattdanger.net/2008/12/adjust-mac-os-x-display-brightness-from-the-terminal/. Does this have anything to do with what you're asking for?

Comment: Your question is perfectly on topic here, no need to be migrated.

Comment: @slhck - thanks! @Nano - that was the first thing I found! It looks potentially utilize-able, but seemed like a great deal more effort than I expected. The heart of my Q here is how can you emulate the output of tapping `F1`? It must be possible... or so I continue to stubbornly assume.

Comment: Also, the mattdanger concludeds with adding in a boot up hook. I would like to have more of a readily-available CLI call.

Comment: You only need the login hook if you want a specific brightness upon booting. `/path/to/brightness` just refers to where you install that program. This is your readily-available CLI call. Except for the `IODisplaySetFloatParameterfunction` call (and determining which display, if it's not all of them) , it's all boilerplate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [`brightness` program](http://mattdanger.net/2008/12/adjust-mac-os-x-display-brightness-from-the-terminal/) from @Nano8Blazex's comment, that is assumed to be installed on your `$PATH`:

Add the following lines to `.bash_profile` (assuming `bash` shell) and you can then use `dim` and `lighten` as commands for `F1` and `F2`, respectively. Both work only on display 0 as listed by `brightness -l`.

```
function modify_brightness {
    local delta=$1
    current=$( brightness -l | grep "display 0: brightness" | cut -d" " -f4 )
    #echo "Current brightness is $current"
    new=$( echo "$current+($delta)" | bc )
    #echo "New brightness is $new"
    COMMAND="brightness -d 0 $new"
    #echo "Executing $COMMAND"
    $COMMAND
}

function dim {
    modify_brightness -0.0625
}

function brighten {
    modify_brightness 0.0625
}
```

Comment: Great choice. I'm running down a rat hole of needing to find a `gcc` option for 10.6 OSX w/o Xcode, but I'll just find my boot dvd and install it. Cheers.

Comment: @mjb That blog page contains a download link for the compiled binary.